# Is it possible to get access to my chrome extension localStorage from my website?

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, web-storage

I built a chrome extension that saves data to localStorage from the background page (using the `chrome.storage.sync.set`).

Now, say that I want to build a website and access to the extension's data on the localStorage from the website, is it possible to access this data from the website domain? maybe I can add something to the manifest file to allow that?

Comment: Well I don't think that you can do this. The applications on the browser including the chrome-extensions work in a sand-box and hence can't access the resources of other.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to inject a content script into your web site and then have your background script pass the localStorage to your content script. As for communication between your content script and the script on your web site, you'll have to get creative.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming here that you are aware of the message passing procedures between the content script and background script.

Now, I don't think your website can make a request to the extension and "pull" data from it, but you can certainly have your extension "push" data to your website.

This is how you can do it:

**Content Script**

The content script should check if the site open in the website is your website, say www.yourwebsite.com

```
if (currentUrl == "www.yourwebsite.com")
{
  ....
}
```

If it is indeed your website, pull the required data from the background script

```
if (currentUrl == "www.yourwebsite.com")
{
  chrome.extension.sendRequest({ "getLocalStorageData": true, "dataFieldName": "favouriteColor" }, handleLocalStorageResult);
}

function handleLocalStorageResult(dataValue)
{
  .....
}
```

On receiving the data in method handleLocalStorageResult, inject the data into the page's html so that your website's javascript can read it

```
if (currentUrl == "www.yourwebsite.com")
{
  chrome.extension.sendRequest({ "getLocalStorageData": true, "dataFieldName": "favouriteColor" }, handleLocalStorageResult);
}

function handleLocalStorageResult(dataValue)
{
  var localStorageDataDiv = $('<div>').appendTo('body');
  localStorageDataDiv.attr('id', 'extensionData');
  localStorageDataDiv.html(dataValue);
}
```

**Your WebSite's Javascript**

Now your website's javascript can read the data

```
var data = $('#extensionData').html();
alert('My Extension's LocalStorage Data is ' + data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers to date do not mention that content scripts and the webpage **share** their `localStorage` object. If your content script writes to `localStorage`, the webpage will be later able to read it, and vice versa.